# How to get the webpage with urllib library?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

The webpage can open in my browser.

https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json

Add browser user agent when to get the webpage with urllib:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = "https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json"
req = Request(
    url=url, 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
)
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

It run into error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Although i can get the webpage with playwright:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright as playwright
pw = playwright().start()
browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()
url = "https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json"
page.goto(url)
page.content()
```

I feel it is a clunky method,how to get the webpage only with urllib?

Comment: Many websites explicitly allow (or deny) connections based on your user-agent header. Possibly setting the user-agent header when using `urllib.request` to match a browser will allow things to work.

Comment: The simpliest way to solve the problem is to set `User-Agent` header to something more meaningful. Like: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the Fair Access section of [SEC.gov | Accessing EDGAR Data](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data), passing a normal browser header from a non-browser client (as you've tried to do) will likely be met with a negative response:

> Please declare your user agent in request headers:
>
> Sample Declared Bot Request Headers:
>
> | [Header] | [Value] |
> | --- | --- |
> | User-Agent: | Sample Company Name AdminContact@.com |
> | Accept-Encoding: | gzip, deflate |
> | Host: | www.sec.gov |

Heeding this advice seems to work [in my test on Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/WoefulFoolishGroupware#main.py):

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = "https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers_exchange.json"
req = Request(
    url=url, 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Sean Quinn email@redacted.com'}
)
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
print(webpage)
```